# How to customize and add PKIXRevocationChecker implementation in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsse, java-security

Btw, I have two questions:

1. Is it correct that if I set Security.property `ocsp.enable=true` and `com.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true`, my application checks certificates in trust stores for revocation (CRL or OCSP) by default?
2. How can I customize PKIXRevocationChecker implementation logic on spring boot application or on non-boot application?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, if your application is using the PKIX implementation of the java.security.cert.CertPathValidator API to validate certificate chains, then revocation checking is enabled by default. It can be disabled by passing `false` to the `setRevocationEnabled` method of `java.security.cert.PKIXParameters`. When the `ocsp.enable` security property is set to `true`, OCSP is used to check revocation (in addition to CRLs). When the `com.sun.security.enableCRLDP` is set to true, it uses the information in a certificate's CRL Distribution Points extension (in addition to CertStores that are specified) to find the CRL.

Also, in JDK 8, the `PKIXRevocationChecker` API was added, which allows more control over how revocation checking is performed.

See the PKI Programmer's Guide for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#PKIXRevocationChecker